# Using Spring's MessageSource for setting FieldError default messages

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

After my form backing object is validated I have a BindingResult, which contains a list of FieldError. Each FieldError has a defaultMessage. How is that message set and why doesn't it use my Spring MessageSource?  I would like that default message to be derived from my Spring's MessageSource.

**EDIT:**
I see that the error codes are being set correctly in the FieldError object.  It's just the default message in that object is not coming from my MessageSource.  For instance, when I enter a string for a field that is an int I want it to get my message from messages.properties:

```
typeMismatch=Invalid type was entered.
```

The only way I can get that message is if I take my FieldError object and pass it into the MessageSource manually like so:

```
messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, null);  // This gets my message from messages.properties.
```

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't remember what we ended up doing on that project.  Unfortunately I no longer have access to the source for that project either.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a [Validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html), you can specify the keys for the messages in the MessageSource in the Validator implementing class, usually using ValidationUtils methods. [Section 6.2 of the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator) has a good example.

Spring will also try to [resolve error codes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-conversion) by convention if you're using something other than a Validator like JSR-303 Bean Validation.

Let's say you had a form backing object called 'Address' with an int field called 'zipcode.' If the user entered a string for the zipcode field, by default Spring will use the [DefaultMessageCodesResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html) and look in the MessageSource for a key called 'typeMismatch.address.zipcode.' If it doesn't find that key, it will try 'typeMismatch.zipcode,' then 'typeMismatch.int,' then 'typeMismatch.'

Or, you can implement your own [MessageCodesResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/MessageCodesResolver.html).

Comment: I can see that the right error codes are being set in the FieldError object.  It's just that the default message in that object is not coming from my MessageSource.  I have to call messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, null) to get my message.  I would like the default message in the FieldError objects to automatically come from my MessageSource.

Comment: Can you add some more specific code samples referencing the object property you are seeing the issue with? Perhaps the bean annotation, the message key, etc?